# Unable to identify where to enable the FirstOrDefaultAsync method for a ASP.NET Core model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, dbset

I'm having difficulty identifying where in a ASP.NET Core app we specify that a model can have the FirstOrDefaultAsync method enabled. I've previously scaffolded two models to razor pages, and for those I can write async method like so:

```cs
component = await Context.component.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

However, for this new model that I scaffolded, I used a view Model but when I swapped the models, I get an error when I use the FirstOrDefaultAsync method.

> 'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've made sure that the necessary namespaces have been included in the file, and the DBContext file includes the model

```cs
public DbSet<update> update { get; set; }
```

I made sure to run dotnet restore and restart VSCode and am unable to find answers searching online or in the documentation

Comment: you didnt show code of how you try to invoke firstordefaultasync and it gives you error

Comment: You can use that extension method anywhere as long as you are referencing the `EntityFramework.dll` and have the line `using System.Data.Entity;`

Answer (score 4):

I thought I made sure I had all the include statements I needed, but somehow `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` got deleted. Re-adding it resolved the issue.